# How do I use the time function in Views Math expression?

Tags: views

I'm having trouble with the Global: Math Expression in a View.  I have an entity type which is a student.  I'd like the student grade level to change automatically from year to year, so I'm storing a graduation year and would like to display grade level by a Math expression.  To do so, I need to include a current time element (month and year).  I have read that time() is useable, but I can't get it to work.  Perhaps I'm using the wrong format in the Expression box under Configure field?  As a test, I put in just time(), but I get a zero at the output.  Is time() useable within Views Math Expressions or do I have to abandon that approach and learn to use the Computed Field module?  If time() is useable, would I be able to convert seconds to years by getting an integer value for time()/60/60/24/365.25 or does is there no integer conversion function here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Views PHP Field, http://drupal.org/project/views_php, you can enter in custom php field information. I would take the original date variable and subtract the date as of now to get the value you want:

```
  //Just creating a random freshman grad date

  $graduation_year = (date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+4 year')));

  $now = (date ('Y-m-d', (strtotime('now'))));

  $diff = abs($graduation_year - $now);
```

Based on the absolute difference in years you can do validation in your views field that validates this information and sets the student as a freshman, sophmore, junior or senior (assuming highschool :) ) based on the $diff value of 1,2,3,4.

That validation would look like:

```
if ($diff == 1) {
print('Senior');
}
elseif($diff == 2){
print('Junior');
}
elseif($diff == 3){
print('Sophmore');
}
elseif($diff == 4){
print('Freshman');
}
```

I didn't put exception handling but you get the idea.

Comment: I was hoping to just use the built in Global: Math Expression rather than adding another module, but I'll do it that way if there isn't a method to simply put in an expression with the time() function.  I suppose being able to use php in Views could be pretty handy in other instances as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, Views PHP evidently doesn't pull the field value correctly through $row.  Found the workaround here: http://drupal.org/node/1516348

Comment: If this idea works for you please select it as the answer

Comment: It works as a workaround, but presents a new problem, since that module has some bugs and is still in dev (was able to get around one bug, but not the second: click to sort doesn't seem to work properly).  It's a partial solution for now.